# ChartImageHandler and web farm environment getting 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, http-status-code-404, web-farm

I am using asp.net `ChartImageHandler` to generate charts in my `.aspx` pages, Everything was working great until we tested application on a web farm environment.

The problem is that for some requests, Chart returns 404 error and cannot find the image, This is the config that we use:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;deleteAfterServicing=false;" />
  </appSettings>
```

I guess that it is because the chart is stored in one server and not stored in the other server.
I have this section in my `web.config` file:

```
<remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
<add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3986ad364e35" />
```

`ChartImageHandler` is present in the handler mapping of site created in IIS.

As said in documentation page [in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd456629(v=vs.140)), What I understand is that for web farm environment, we should set the storage to `file` and the other two options are not applicable to web farm environment.

the `dir` path should be a network path and I tried this network path but it didn't work either ! here what the config look like with the network directory:

And also the network address `\\serverIp\TempImageFiles` is accessible from windows explorer.

Any suggestion for making this work is much appreciated !

Edit: We changed the affinity of load balancer and everything worked fine.

Comment: Ensure that your application pool identity user has read and write permissions on the network path set at `dir`

Comment: we have added Network Service the full permission to the folder.

Comment: You confirmed that application pool identity is set to `Network Service`? Also, is it intermittent issue? Confirm that image files are generated in shared directory

Comment: Every thing is set to default, I really don't know about pool identity, yes it is intermittent issue, when I set the `dir` directory application crashes.